# Issues with ajax / jquery site - content loads incorrectly into page

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I am using Gallery Bank with Alive theme on this website: http://www.gabrielaholcer.com/art/drawings/

But the fancybox – full image view doesn’t load correctly. It tries to open fancybox, then instead, the image is loaded old fashion way into the window, replacing all content. And for some strange reason, the screen freezes, when you click back button, URL changes but contents of the screen don’t. Only after you refresh page. Try it by clicking on the first image just below “drawings” (guy with beer). Same thing happens with Jetpack Social icons - clicking on FB share opens the FB popup window, but it also opens it in the main window.

I can’t figure out what bit of code is your plugin or the theme crashing on?

I tried deactivating all other plugins, no change.

Hope you might have previous experience and know where to look with this type of issue (I realize that it’s more likely an issue with the theme, but it could also be a known issue with jquery / ajax sites that you are familiar with).

thanks!
Lukas

Comment: Replace `$(document).keydown(function(event) ...` by `jQuery(document).keydown(function(event) ...`

Comment: There might be a problem with importing jquery. Please check to make sure you have included jquery in the html.

Comment: Thanks JFK & Snehal. replacing the call didn't work although not sure if I replaced it in all needed places. But - your comments got me digging more and I realized that it's an old template I'm using and all the jquery files are old too. So I started replacing the old version by their new versions one by one and it was down to an outdated version of jquery.fancybox.pack.js.

Lesson learned - don't troubleshoot the code before you are sure you have the latest versions :)

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, not this introduced a new problem>  pages don't reload (when I click on a new page in the menu from an existing page, the URL changes, but screen doesn't change.

Probably something to do with jquery.history.js

Will dig around and post a new question, not to mix things up here.

Answer (score 0):

for future refernce, here's what fixed it - updating the jquery.fancybox.pack.js file. Not sure which bit of code, but the template I'm using is older and it carried prepacked old .js files.